# SQLite Table error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am working with SQLite in Android. I have only 1 object in my table i.e. name. I want to make arraylist and use it in recyclerview. But i am getting error given below. With it I got that there is some problem with cursor but don't now what.

Error

```
Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 7 rows, 1 columns.
```

Code to

```
public List<FavNames> getFav(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlMasterSelect = {"name"};
    String sqlMasterTable = "FavNames";

    qb.setTables(sqlMasterTable);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db,sqlMasterSelect,
            null,null,null,null,null);

    final List<FavNames> masterResult = new ArrayList<>();

    if (c.moveToFirst()){

        do {
            masterResult.add(new FavNames(c
                    .getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"))));

        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return masterResult;

}
```

RecyclerView

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.favRecycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    fav = new Database(this).getFav();
    adapter = new FavAdapter(getBaseContext(), fav);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the column name is `name`  
You don't need SQLiteQueryBuilder for such a simple query.

```
public List<FavNames> getFav(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    String sqlMasterTable = "FavNames";
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + sqlMasterTable;

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    final List<FavNames> masterResult = new ArrayList<>();

    if (c.moveToFirst()){

        do {
            masterResult.add(new FavNames(c.getString(0).toString()));                    

        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return masterResult;

}
```

It's just a simple rawQuery  
I hope I have no typos.

Comment: Still same error - "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it."

Comment: Are you sure thecolumn's name is `name`?

Comment: That solved the error, but now its not populating the Recyclerview

Comment: This is another question for you to post after you debug

Comment: Anyways, Thank you.